# MediaStream does not supported on Android 8

Tags: javascript, react-native, webrtc, mediastream

I am implementing the video conference on React Native. I am using react-native-webrtc npm package. Here is what I do:

1. I try to grab the local stream by WebRTC.getUserMedia method.
2. I add it to PeerConnection using addStream method.

It works fine if we use Android version less than 8. When I use Android 8 then the Streaming doesn't show up on both the ends. Please help.